# Sequelize: update by column it's old value

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-update, sequelize.js

i am trying to update a set of data using Sequelize by this query

```
Users.update({
    flag: 'flag & ~ 2'
} , {
    where : {
        id :{
            gt : 2
        }
    }
})
```

the generated query is

```
UPDATE `users` SET `flag`='flag & ~ 2' WHERE id > 2
```

But is should be

```
UPDATE `users` SET `flag`=flag & ~ 2 WHERE id > 2
```

so my question is how can i update data by by it's old value

Regards

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to do this via:

```
Users.update({
    flag: sequelize.literal('flag & ~ 2')
} , {
    where : {
        id :{
            gt : 2
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be by using [raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/):

```
sequelize.query("UPDATE users SET flag=flag & ~ 2 WHERE id > 2").spread(function(results, metadata) {
  // Results will be an empty array and metadata will contain the number of affected rows.
})
```

Comment: thanks hexerei i know this solution but i don't want to write a raw query

Comment: i am afraid you might find no other solution in one query. otherwise you would have to select value first, do your modification locally and update result. In the context of `Users.update(...)` you don't have a ***this*** pointing to the row, so you can't use the get functions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30145792/831499 for a solution with one query using `sequelize.literal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with sequelize literal.

```
model.update({'count': sequelize.literal('count + 1')}, { where: { id: 1 }})
```

You can also do it with the increment method where by indicates from what value you want to increment.

```
Model.increment('seq', { by: 5, where: { id: 'model_id' });
```